SSH Connectivity Issues on Ubuntu Server with Static IP Configuration
Installed Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS in my old laptop, currently I am connecting to the server using SSH in the same network. I have configured static IP to the server using, changed SSH port(77777 -> dummy value) to different one and updated the sshd_config file.
Port 77777
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlps:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - <Static IP>
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      access-points:
        "WIFI_NAME":
          password: "PASSWORD"

Sometimes randomly I am unable to connect to the server. This issue happened multiple times, recently wait time before I connect to the server has increased to more than 30-40 minutes. I am using mac to connect to the server via SSH key. While the server is unreachable it throws host down error and I am unable to ping the server. When I use verbose while SSH I get:
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling

Then after some time I can connect to the server again.
I have tested few things on the server side

UFW settings are configured to allow the traffic from anywhere to ssh port & other port(77777).

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
77777/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
77777/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6) 


I keep the server up all the time.
Server is able to reach internet via ping command
The server has same ip every time I have checked using ip a

3: wlps: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bb:aa:aa:45:a2:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet {STATIC_IP}/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global wlps
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ipv6 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


SSH server is up and running
Restarted the network interface sudo ip link set wlsp0 down & sudo ip link set wlsp0 up.
Logged into my router and checked if any other device has same IP, but only server has it.

I am confused why this issue is repeating? cannot reproduce the error, this happens randomly.
Edit: The issue happened again, error when I try to SSH into server:
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to <server_static_ip> [<server_static_ip>] port 77777.
debug1: connect to address <server_static_ip> port 77777: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host <server_static_ip> port 77777: Operation timed out

My SSH Server is active:
user@hostname% sudo systemctl status sshd
• ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Loaded: loaded (/us/Lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active:
active (running)
TriggeredBy:
• ssh.socket
since Tue 2024-07-16 18:26:21 UTC; 1 day 15h ago
Docs: man: sshd (8)
man: sshd_conf ig (5)
Main PID: 9816 (sshd)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 28479)
Memory:
2.3M
(peak: 5.2M)
CPU: 240ms
CGroup:
/system.slice/ssh.service
"sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"
sshd 3550197]: Accepted publickey for <user> from <mac_ip_add> port 61200 ssh2: ED28819 SHA256:ThisIsSSHKey332 KJAKnkjnckjs+KJjk3bkjbKBKjbd
Jul 17

sshd [3550197]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <user> (uid=1000) by <user> (uid=0)
10:42:00 hostname

user@hostname% ip route
sshd [3627175]: pam_unixsshd:session): session opened for user <user> (uid=1000) by <user> (uid=0)
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlps proto static
by user (uid=0)
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlps proto kernel scope link src <server_static_ip>

My server Static IP is same as before not changed and Server can access internet
user@hostname ~ & ping
www-google.com
iNG www.google.com (142.250.65.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164): icp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=21.4 ms
64 bytes from lga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164):icmp_seq=2
ttl=118 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from 1ga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164):icmp_seq=3 tt1=118 time=21.7 ms
64 bytes from 1ga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164):icmp_seq=4 tt1=118 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from 1ga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164):icmp_seq=5 tt1=118 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 1ga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164):icmp_seq=6 tt1=118 time=23.1 ms
64 bytes from 1ga25s71-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.65.164):icmp_seq=7 ttl=118 time=21.8 ms
C
-- www.google.com ping statistics ---I packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.364/22.126/23.115/0.561 ms

user@hostname ~ % ip a
wlps: «BROADCAST, MULTICAST,UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether bc:a8:a6:95:a3:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet <server_static_ip> brd 192.168.2.255 scope global ulpsse
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 9999:9999:8888:8888:1222/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


I have checked the SSH keys in my server ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and my machine ~/.ssh/my_rsa_key.pub --> This is same as the one in the Server.
~/.ssh/config in my machine
HOST *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_rsa_key
  UseKeyChain yes

I can see the server is in known host file~/.ssh/know_hosts
edit2: Configured reserved ip address in router for my server
I cannot assign IP address out of my router DHCP assignment. So I reserved the IP address to the server. Its working for few minutes and again stopped working. Now when i try to ping the server I get Host is down. The ip address I have reserved in the router and static ip configured in the server is same.
I can ssh into my server within the server and did all other checks as
specified in the question they are good. Although I cannot point to specific thing, I think the issue is with the network.
edit3: configured ethernet and disabled the wifi
Configured the ethernet and assigned static ip with in the router DHCP range. Mapped the static ip to the server in the router settings.

SSH is up and running
ip a shows the static ip in the eth0

Now I can ping to the server static ip and I can ssh into the server as well.
Thanks @user68186 for helping me. Thanks @Thomas Ward ♦
I will try to use ethernet for these kind of use cases.

I read your question again. Is it possible to use an Ethernet cable to connect the server to the router even if temporarily to rule out buggy WiFi signal or hardware? If the laptop does not have an Ethernet port you will need an Ethernet to USB adapter.

NORMALLY I would attribute this to you using wifi.  It's never reliable for something you're trying to use as a server or SSH to.  Ethernet cabling is superior for those use cases.
